# Meteor Tinytest packages dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, tinytest

I like to test my code. I like to compartmentalize my code into packages. And I like Meteor. Now I'm trying Meteor Tinytest `meteor test-packages`, but I'm getting some weirdness. For example:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Email' of undefined
```

Because of `SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email`. But this code works when it's not tested. Also, `SimpleSchema` is an object at this point (checked through `console.log`), and `SimpleSchema.RegEx` is undefined indeed, but this is completely not what I expected.

Adding `api.use('aldeed:simple-schema', ['server']);` to the onTest section of `package.js` doesn't do anything, which is kind of expected. But I'm not sure what I *am* to do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a bug: [Package.js api.use() loads very old versions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4170), which (mostly) doesn't matter for your application but it matters a lot when you're testing packages individually.

*to be updated*